# Accessing list data from another site collection or web application using REST services?

Tags: jquery, spservices, rest

I have a list (Links template) of URLs that is on a site collection and I was wondering if it is possible to include this list as a jQuery megamenu on another site - ideally another web application on the farm.

I hear it is not possible with the Client Object Model but was wondering about the SharePoint REST services using knockout.js or SPServices?

Has anyone done this and can provide examples?

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 2):

SPServices doesn't "do" REST (yet), but the SOAP Web Services which it does support may well work for you. You can pass a webURL to many Web Services operations (as noted in the docs), including GetListItems, which sounds like the one you want.

I've seen way too many truly odd network topologies and authentication models to say whether this will work in your situation or not, but it may well do it.

Set it up and if it doesn't work initially take a look at the Net traffic with Firebug or Fiddler to see where things are getting stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Try below,

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    webURL: "http://abc", //Site collection URL which has the required List data
    listName: "Medi", //Your list name
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>", //Add the internal names of required fields
    CAMLRowLimit: 10, //Row limit for the list querrying
    CAMLQuery:"<Query></Query>", //Include filters to the query
    CAMLQueryOptions:"<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive'/></QueryOptions>" //Query options
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) 
    {
      //Code to do on a successful submisison
     }
  });
```

For getting familiriazed with SPService refer below link.
http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5

Comment: Correct Answer, it works 100%

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of SharePoint, and how you've got it configured, it's really easy to use Jquery to invoke REST services.

The URLs look something like this:

`http://[YOUR SERVER]/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/[YOUR LIST NAME]`

The URL, including the list name, is case sensitive.

The official Microsoft documentation has a [basic example using Jquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) (scroll down to 'Using the REST Interface from Javascript').

You can find more examples [here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Got-REST-Querying-SharePoint-List-data-using-REST-services-client-side-Part-1.aspx) and [here](http://www.synergyonline.com/blog/lists/posts/post.aspx?id=35).

Comment: Did you leave something out after `...like this:`?